# Mootools LightFace plugin and Mootools tooltips integration

Tags: javascript, mootools

I am using [Light Face plugin](http://davidwalsh.name/facebook-lightbox) written by davidwalsh in my project. In that I am loading content from another page. That page contains a form. I want [mootools tooltip](http://mootools.net/docs/more/Interface/Tips) on form elements, but tool tips are not being displayed in the light face dialog. If I remove the lightface.css file, the tooltips are displayed correctly. So it may be a css error, but I am unable to detect whats happening and I am a newbie in css.

Comment: where's the code? build a use case on jsfiddle.net or nobody would touch this. you can ask david walsh himself on his blog.

Answer (score 0):

I am able to solve the question by the help of davidwalsh himself. It was a problem related with z-index. The `z-index` of the lightface was `9001`, I changed the `z-index` of the tooltip to `9002` and changed "position" of tool tip to "relative".